# Zooko's-Triangle

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I was trying to create a tag for "zooko's-triangle" but accidentally created two erroneous tags: "zooko" and "s-triangle" instead.

Now under the impression that the apostrophe cannot be included in a tag I created "zooko-triangle" instead.

Please delete the "zooko" and "s-triangle" tags.

Comment: thanks @ᴡᴏʀᴅs I like that so many things on stackexchange are automated

Comment: Wouldn't "zooko-s-triangle" be better ?

Comment: @ClementJ I was not sure if there was a customs for these apostrophe situations.  I have no strong feelings either way between "zooko-s-triangle"  and "zooko-triangle"

Comment: No strong feeling either, my idea is that it may be easier to read with the "s". The rare tags with apostrophes I've found use yet an other convention: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goldbachs-conjecture and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascals-triangle (so "zookos-triangle" if we want to follow that).

Comment: @ClementJ. Now I tend to favor "zookos-triangle" but we can wait to hear input from more people since we both appear someone indifferent.

Comment: I'm definitely leaning towards ```zookos-triangle```, it reads better to my eyes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based upon the above comments it appears an early consensus in favor of `zookos-triangle` has been reached.